# When and why should I use a domain service?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have a Rental entity that is an aggregate root. Among other things it maintains a list of Allocations (chunks of time that is reserved).

How do I add a new allocation? Since Rental is aggregate root, any new allocation should go through it but it is impossible to say if a rental can be allocated, before we try to save the allocation in the database. Another user could have reserved it in the meantime. I'm guessing, I should use a Domain Service for this?

I would hate to have to inject *anything* every time I need a new Rental but what is the difference between injecting a Domain Service, instead of a Repository, other than the terminology being different?

Comment: Is your system so huge that you need to load-balance and run various instances of your domain logic? If not, then every client would rent via the same instance of your bounded context and the conflict could be resolved in your domain logic code independent of database writes.

Comment: Yes. We're using a Microservice Architecture so the system is designed to run several instances of the Booking Service simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When and why should I use a domain service?

You use a domain service to allow an aggregate to run queries.  Tax calculation is an example that shows up form time to time.  The aggregate passes some state to the calculator, the calculator reports the tax, the aggregate decides what to do with that information (ignore it, reject the update that needs it, etc).

Running the query doesn't modify the domain service instance in any way, so you can repeat queries as often as you like without worrying that the calculations contaminate each other.

Think read only service provider.

> Since Rental is aggregate root, any new allocation should go through it but it is impossible to say if a rental can be allocated, before we try to save the allocation in the database. Another user could have reserved it in the meantime. I'm guessing, I should use a Domain Service for this?

No - completely the wrong use case.

If an allocation is part of the Rental aggregate, then it's fine to have the Rental aggregate create allocations of its own.  You don't need a service for that (you could, potentially, delegate the work to a factory if you like separation of concerns).

If "another user could have reserved that allocation in the meantime", then you have contention -- two users trying to change the same aggregate at the same time.  This is normally managed in one of two ways.

Locking: you only let one user at a time modify the Rental aggregate.  So in a data race, the loser has to wait for the winner to finish, then the aggregate can reject the loser's command because that particular allocation is already taken.

Optimistic concurrency: you allow both users to modify different copies of the aggregate at the same time, but save is only allowed if the original state is unchanged.  Think "compare and swap"; the race is in the save, between these two instructions

```
state.compareAndSwap(originalState, loserState)
state.compareAndSwap(originalState, winnerState)
```

Winner's compare and swap succeeds, but the loser's fails (because originalState != winnerState), and so the losers modification is rejected.

Either way, only one write to your database reserving the allocation is allowed.

> If I understand you correctly, you're saying that in this case it would be okay to use a repository from inside the Rental domain entity?

No, you shouldn't need to - the allocation, being part of the Rental aggregate, gets created by the aggregate in memory, and first appears in your data store when the aggregate is saved.

> Why use aggregates at all, if everything of consequence has to be extracted into surrounding code or factories?

Some of the answer here is separation of concerns - the primary concern of the aggregate is enforcing the business invariant: ensuring that creating an allocation with some specific state is consistent with everything else going on.  The factory is responsible for ensuring that the created object is wired up correctly.

To use your example: the factory would have responsibility for creating the allocation in memory, but would not need to know anything about making sure that the allocation is unique.  The rules to ensure that the allocation is unique are described and enforced by the aggregate.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're saying that in this case it would be okay to use a repository from inside the Rental domain entity? We are running multiple instances of these services so any locking on a code level is not going to work. I could look into optimistic concurrency, but then my domain model feels handicapped. My operations on my domain entities become irrelevant since any state change or value returned is a guess, until the surrounding code checks with the database. Why use aggregates at all, if everything of consequence has to be extracted into surrounding code or factories?

Comment: I am still not completely sure how I want to proceed with my specific problem, but now I know what not to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use a static factory method to create a Rental object.

```
public static class RentalFactory
{
    public Rental CreateRental()
    {
        var allocationSvc = new RentalAllocationService();
        return new Rental(allocationSvc);
    }
}
```

Repositories should only be concerned about persistence to underlying store.
Domain services primary concern is carrying out some behavior involving entities or value objects.

Comment: But checking and then saving is not reliable in this scenario. In order for the Rental aggregate to return anything usable, it has to try to write the new allocation to the database - meaning trying to persist the information. Otherwise the Rental.Allocate method would just be "add to internal list and cross your fingers".